# CRM procurement: Presenting the case for CiviCRM

Tags: evaluating-civicrm

I have a list of functionality requirements for a new CRM system. I have run through this spec with a number of alternative CRM providers, who have given answers regarding what their systems can/can't do. How can I run through this list to consider CiviCRM?

Comment: You could contact one of the Partners and see if you could get some quick assessment from them to help you on the way. Fuzion would be happy to make someone available for a first round of assessment if you want.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [the recent Idealware report](http://www.idealware.org/reports/consumers-guide-low-cost-donor-management-systems/) comparing 'donor management systems' and CRMs. I do not believe it is totally accurate or fair to CiviCRM, but it is something like what you want.

CiviCRM members are working on a side-by-side comparison of CiviCRM to 'competitor' platforms, which we hope to publish soon at [the CiviCRM.org website.](http://www.civicrm.org)

Comment: @SHodges you're welcome. Have you had a chance to review some comparisons, and have thoughts or questions?

Comment: Yes Joe, thank you. I have reviewed and advised my employer to now outsource our CRM project to a specialist consultant. Fundraising & Comms is my area - I think better to outsource the technical side of things to the pros!  Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Could you explain what your requirements are and which platform you would be using i.e. Drupal, Wordpress or Joomla.

It would probably be a good idea for you to start by reading the CiviCRM User Guide at https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/  This would give you a good basic explanation of what CiviCRM can do.

Hope this helps.